# Kubernetes: calculate external outgoing traffic by namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, traffic

In Kuberenetes I can get all outgoing traffic for every namespace from prometheus. But I need divide it to internal and external traffic.

Does anybody knows way to get **external outgoing traffic for every namespace** in Kubernetes?

Comment: There was a hope that at least the bandwidth control problem could be solved with the plugin https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/tree/master/plugins/meta/bandwidth. I will write about the results.